# How do I convert a date/time to HST in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, utc

Trying to convert a date string to HST time, but it does not work.

Relevant code:

```
var MINUTES_IN_MILLI = 60000,
    HOURS_IN_MILLI = 3600000,
    UTC2HST_OFFSET = 10,
    date1 = new Date('2013-05-31T00:00:00Z'),
    utc1 = date1.getTime() + (date1.getTimezoneOffset() * MINUTES_IN_MILLI),
    hstDate1 = utc1 - (HOURS_IN_MILLI * UTC2HST_OFFSET);
```

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it?  And why are you putting it all in one statement with commas?  What exactly is "HST"?  I might guess you are in Hawaii, but I might be guessing wrong.

Comment: it does not seem to give me the time in HST (Hawaii).

Comment: You need to provide more detail.  This code actually doesn't give you anything, because you're just setting some variables.  The output of `hstDate1` would be a number, not a date.  Please provide a complete sample. Show what you are getting, and what you expect.  Also, are you actually *in* Hawaii and just looking for local time?   What if the user is somewhere else - should it show Hawaii time still - or their own time?

Comment: Also, what browser are you targeting?  The ISO formatted date string you are starting with is not supported in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I will go out on a limb and say that the problem is that you are introducing both a known fixed offset (10 hours), and a derived offset from `getTimezoneOffset()`.

You probably don't want:

```
utc1 = date1.getTime() + (date1.getTimezoneOffset() * MINUTES_IN_MILLI)
```

From the variable name you gave it, I assume you want the UTC timestamp, so just do:

```
utc1 = date1.getTime()
```

But without additional information as I requested in comments, I can't be sure that this is really what you are after.  Please update your question and I will modify this answer as necessary.